# VBA to click within Print Preview window in IE11

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I would like to write a macro to click the print icon (Alt+P) within print preview window in IE11. 
I thought of using **FindWindow, FindWindowEx, SendMessage and PostMessage functions**.
But when I checked the window info, there seemed to be no button for clicking the print icon.[Print Preview Window Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC8jO.jpg)

Wherever I click within the window, it displays only InternetExplorer_TridentDlgFrame in Class. So how should I click the print icon?

**I do not want to use Sendkeys or to perform mouse click based on the location as I would be using this macro in different systems.**

So is there any suitable way to do this? Any ideas will be very useful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

see here for details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752117(v=vs.85).aspx

```
Option Explicit

Sub printIE()

    Const OLECMDID_PRINT = 6            ' declarations needed for late binding only if mnemonics are desired in ExecWB command
    Const OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW = 7

    Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT = 0
    Const OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
    Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
    Const OLECMDEXECOPT_SHOWHELP = 3

    Dim IE As Object                    ' late binding

'   Dim IE As InternetExplorer          ' early binding ... reference microsoft internet controls

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'   IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate ("google.co.in")

    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
    Loop

    IE.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER

'   IE.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't use this code as I am doing only webpage automation. I can't change the source code where it is already specified as IE.ExecWB 7,1

Comment: what exactly are you doing? which programming language are you using?
 please post the code that you are using, if possible

Comment: I have a webpage with manuals. I have to use vba & IE to convert those to pdf. There is a print button within the webpage, clicking which will open the print preview window with user prompt.

Comment: It is an intranet site so I can't share/modify the source code

Comment: examine the print button (right click ... inspect). it may have the link to the actual URL of the manual

Comment: The print button code calls ie.execwb(7,1) to the current page. The page has an URL but the serial numbers in it keep changing..so can't use it

Comment: the serial number may be someplace else on the page

Comment: someplace else?

Comment: look for it in the html